# cat6 wall connector. 2 wires 1 connector?

Tags: cat6, wired

Do you guys know the best connectors to get for a cat6 configuration? The total cable length is 100FT so its not huge but I have it going strait through with 4 total connectors. I want to wire the middle ones so that they not only give the wall jack to plug into but they also connect the 2 wires together (right now its uncut) so that I don't have to do this outside the wall and connect a short cable between the 2 to continue the connection (if no switch is needed there).

I was thinking of wiring bundles of wire (16 total wires) into one wall connector. The other though is to strip the plastic off the cable and leave it uncut then just pass it through.

What are you thoughts? or do they sell wall connectors that takes 2 sets of wire to 1 outlet?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do. Could you rephrase your question, please? Should you think about opening/combining the cables, forget about it, this is a very bad idea, as the shielding is there for a reason.

Comment: @SvenW: I think Zypher has it http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1611891#1611891

Comment: Dude, you have to check out this video… search Youtube for 'two wires one connector'…

Comment: They do make in-wall switches, but that's a lot more money than running more cable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It. Does. Not. Work. That. Way.

[Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) over Cat5/6/7 is point to point only. It does not work like a telephone line (despite looking similar). Each wire must go only from one device to one other device.

Comment: *somewhere* I've seen some 2-port ethernet switches that are small enough to fit in a backbox (or at least, wall cavity)  Can't find em now tho.

Comment: @Tom; A long time ago I'm sure I've seen something like that; punchdown on the back and a couple ports on the front. I haven't seen anything like that in a very long time though; and I'm pretty sure it was 10base-t or maybe 10/100.

Comment: Not punchdown on the back, but a mini-switch in a wall box: http://www.lctinc.net/pages/nj220_features.asp  I've got a couple samples they sent me, never got around to using them.

Comment: I can run the homeleads, I just didnt want 1 box with 4 connectors into it (or a mini patch panel) but that is why i'm verifying before doing it. I'm assuming the topology would work but only one device would be able to connect through it.

Comment: Ethernet over copper is quite intolerant of reflected signals, which you'd get from every dead run along the path (or past the path). If might work at the lowest speeds but likely not at anything higher.